# VBA 2016 compatibility issue

Tags: excel, vba

The code works fine in Excel 2013 and Excel 2010 - but in Excel 2016 it shows error:

> Run time error 9 - subscript out of range

Can you help. The code just sorts a column and hides it.

```
Sub abc()
    Sheets("Top_Issue").Visible = True
    Sheets("Top_Issue").Select
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
    Range(Cells(1, "p"), Cells(lastrow, "p")).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Top_Issue").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Top_Issue").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("P1"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Top_Issue").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:S" & lastrow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Sheets("Top_Issue").Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I have excel 2016 and that code ran successfully for me.  I wasn't able to get it to error out.

Comment: Which line of code is returning the error?

Comment: One more check that it runs in Excel 2016. Are you sure that your workbook does not have some events, that may go triggered during running the code? The mistake could be there.

Comment: On top of the specific line/instruction throwing the error, it would also be useful to know if the `Top_Issue` sheet exists in `ThisWorkbook` (the file that contains this code) or not.

Answer (score 2):

You have implicit references to the `ActiveSheet` here:

```
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
Range(Cells(1, "p"), Cells(lastrow, "p")).Select
```

The above unqualified `Range` member calls are equivalent to this:

```
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, "p"), ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, "p")).Select
```

Code that uses `.Select`/`.Activate` and implicitly refers to the active sheet is very likely to eventually blow up whenever an assumption is broken, for example when the `ActiveWorkbook` isn't the workbook the code is assuming.

You're pulling the object reference for that `Top_Issue` sheet 6 times; sometimes from `ActiveWorkbook`, sometimes using the `Sheets` collection, other times using the `Worksheets` collection, with `.Select` calls in between.

Start with a `With` block, and make sure all `Range` and `Worksheet` member calls are properly qualified:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Top_Issue")
    .Visible = True
    .Select
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(.Cells(1, "p"), .Cells(lastrow, "p")).Select
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("P1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With .Sort
        .SetRange .Range("A2:S" & lastrow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    .Visible = False
End With
```

If the `Top_Issue` sheet exists at compile-time in `ThisWorkbook`, set its `(Name)` property (in the *Properties* toolwindow <kbd>F4</kbd>) to, e.g. `TopIssueSheet`, and use that identifier instead of pulling from the `Worksheets` collection.

Note that `ActiveWorkbook` (the currently active book) may or may not be `ThisWorkbook` (the book that contains this code) - if the wrong book is active, and it doesn't have a `Top_Issue` sheet, that's why you're getting run-time error 9.

Using a *code name* for the worksheet, you no longer need to care about which workbook might be active:

```
With TopIssueSheet
    ...
End With
```

You should only ever need to pull a worksheet from a workbook's `Worksheets` collection when you're working off a workbook that isn't `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: @ mat - it is giving run time error '438' for the above code -

<code>  .SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("P1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal <code>

Comment: @Shyam gah, it's because the `With` block is scoped to the `.Sort`; `.Range` isn't a member. Fixed.

Comment: Also, see if removing that `.Select` call changes anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Sheets code instead of Worksheets name. `Sheet1`, etc...

Also, note that Sheets collection and Worksheets collection are two different things.

Comment: That is good and sound advice (use sheet codenames, and the `Worksheets` collection to retrieve a `Worksheet`), but doesn't answer the question (not my downvote).

Comment: Actually.. using codenames instead of pulling them from `Sheets`/`Worksheets` might very well fix OP's problem.

Comment: @Shyam watch for implicit `ActiveSheet` references too. `Cells` and `Range` member calls that aren't qualified, implicitly refer to whatever sheet is active. But you mostly need to tell us *which specific line* is throwing the error.

Comment: Sorry guys.. Been away for long time.. Looks like only in that system we have issues.. I have tested the code in 2016, 2013 and 2010 in different PC - its working file.. But for some reason it does not on that PC. However there was no visible corruption - Also checked the references.. if any for missing bit - So will try a reinstall on that to check.. Thank you for all your support - I wanna close this query - will try from my end..

You Guys are Awesome.. love this site.